# Problem with boxes distribution in poster format (baposter)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, posters, baposter

The box called "Materials and methods" is not aligned with the bottom of the box "introduction." How can I fix it?
The auxiliary files and the main code can be found in the link:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/bskjppttymwm

This is my code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% LaTeX Template for IAHR YPN Congress

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage{amsmath} % For typesetting math
\usepackage{amssymb} % Adds new symbols to be used in math mode

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables
\usepackage{enumitem} % Used to reduce itemize/enumerate spacing
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for multiple columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em} % Slightly increase the space between columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % No horizontal rule between columns

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for flow chart
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz libraries required for the flow chart in the template

\newcommand{\compresslist}{ % Define a command to reduce spacing within itemize/enumerate environments, this is used right after \begin{itemize} or \begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Defines the color used for content box headers

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}
{
headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=lightblue, % Border color
headerColorOne=black, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=lightblue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.1\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{\includegraphics[height=6em]{kaust-logo-3.png}} % First university/lab logo on the left
{\bf\textsc{Discovery of Hidden Control Variables 
 on Non-Linear Biological Systems}\vspace{0.5em}} % Poster title
{\textsc{Juan Munoz, Subash Balsamy, Juan Bernal, Ali Balubaid, David Gomez, Narsis Kiani \& Jesper Tegner}} % Author names and institution
{\includegraphics[height=9em]{karolinska-institutet.png}} % Second university/lab logo on the right

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Abstract}{name=abstract,column=0,row=0}{
How to construct robust dynamical models for biological systems constitute a grand challenge for the systems biology community that is still unresolved: 

\begin{itemize}\compresslist
    \item Several putative model architectures could be formulated for given biological systems,
    \item parameter space is massive for each model,
    \item hidden variables exist controlling the system, but we have no data for their temporal evolution. 
\end{itemize}
\vspace{0.3em}

\textbf{Our method HINNDY:} 

\begin{itemize}\compresslist
    \item using normal forms as universal, scalable, and minimal dynamical building blocks,
    \item Samples observations in the vicinity of a slow manifold.
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Results:}

We effectively discover the underlying equations and unobserved hidden variables from data generated from the toggle switch, genetic oscillator, and Waddington landscape model.

\vspace{0.3em}

\textbf{Keywords:} Data-Driven Prediction, System Identification, Hidden Variables

\vspace{0.3em} % When there are two boxes, some whitespace may need to be added if the one on the right has more content
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\headerbox{Results 1: Validation}{name=results,column=2,span=2,row=0}{
\headerbox{Materials \& Methods}{name=introduction, column=1, row=0, bottomaligned=method, above=references}{

% \headerbox{Materials \& Methods}{name=method, column=1, row=0, above=references}{

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Figure sub1.2 HINNDy.png}
\captionof{figure}{Method}
\end{center}


}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESULTS 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Results 1: Validation}{name=results,column=2,span=2,row=0}{

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Fig2.1.V2.png}
\captionof{figure}{Discovered qualitatively behavior of hidden variables using normal form }
\end{center}


}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{References}{name=references,column=0,above=bottom}{

\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em} % Get rid of the default "References" section title
\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster
\small{ % Reduce the font size in this block
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sample} % Use sample.bib as the bibliography file
}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FUTURE RESEARCH
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Future Research}{name=futureresearch,column=1,span=2,aligned=references,above=bottom}{ % This block is as tall as the references block

We will develop a data-driven workflow using machine learning (ML) techniques. We believe that constraining a ML predictive model using normal forms is the first step toward a more data-driven workflow to formulate systems biology models. 
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Contact Information}{name=contact,column=3,aligned=references,above=bottom}{ % This block is as tall as the references block

\begin{description}\compresslist
\item[Email]\url{juan.munozdiaz@kaust.edu.sa}
\item[Whatsapp] +966 545754957
\end{description}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONCLUSION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Results 2: Discovery for unknown systems equations}{name=conclusion,column=2,span=2,row=0,below=results,above=references}{

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{Fig2.2 HINNDy.png}
\captionof{figure}{Figure caption}
\end{center}

}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MATERIALS AND METHODS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Introduction}{name=method,column=0,below=abstract,bottomaligned=conclusion}{ % This block's bottom aligns with the bottom of the conclusion block

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{FigApplicationPoster.png}
\captionof{figure}{Applications}
\end{center}

}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESULTS 2
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% \headerbox{}{name=results2,column=1,below=abstract,bottomaligned=conclusion}{ % This block's bottom aligns with the bottom of the conclusion block

% \begin{center}
% \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Methods2.2.png}
% \captionof{figure}{Applications}
% \end{center}

% }

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this template to add the material.

[image: A]

The bottom row must be defined at the beginning so that other boxes can use it as a reference (such as "introduction"); then "materials" and "results2" can be bottom aligned with "introduction" bottom.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% LaTeX Template for IAHR YPN Congress

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage{amsmath} % For typesetting math
\usepackage{amssymb} % Adds new symbols to be used in math mode

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables
\usepackage{enumitem} % Used to reduce itemize/enumerate spacing
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for multiple columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em} % Slightly increase the space between columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % No horizontal rule between columns

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for flow chart
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz libraries required for the flow chart in the template

\newcommand{\compresslist}{ % Define a command to reduce spacing within itemize/enumerate environments, this is used right after \begin{itemize} or \begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Defines the color used for content box headers

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}
{
headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=lightblue, % Border color
headerColorOne=black, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=lightblue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.1\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{\includegraphics[height=6em]{example-image-a}} % First university/lab logo on the left
{\bf\textsc{Discovery of Hidden Control Variables 
 on Non-Linear Biological Systems}\vspace{0.5em}} % Poster title
{\textsc{Juan Munoz, Subash Balsamy, Juan Bernal, Ali Balubaid, David Gomez, Narsis Kiani \& Jesper Tegner}} % Author names and institution
{\includegraphics[height=6em]{example-image-b}} % Second university/lab logo on the right

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Abstract}{name=abstract,column=0,row=0}{%    
    Some space
    \vspace*{100pt} % filler space
}

%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\headerbox{References}{name=references,column=0,above=bottom}{% 
    Some space
    \vspace*{30pt} % filler space   
}

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  FUTURE RESEARCH
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Future Research}{name=futureresearch,column=1,span=2,aligned=references, above=bottom}{ % This block is as tall as the references block
    
    Empty but top aligned with references
}
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  CONTACT INFORMATION
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
\headerbox{Contact Information}{name=contact,column=3,aligned=references, above=bottom}{ % This block is as tall as the references block
        Empty but top aligned with references
}

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  INTRODUCTION
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\headerbox{Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,below=abstract, above=references}{% 
        Empty but bottom aligned with references top
}

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  MATERIALS AND METHODS
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                        
\headerbox{Materials \& Methods}{name=materials, column=1, row=0, bottomaligned= introduction}{%
        Empty but bottom aligned with introduction bottom
}

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  RESULTS 1
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Results 1: Validation}{name=results1,column=2,span=2,row=0}{%
        Some space
        \vspace*{150pt} % filler space
}


%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  RESULTS 2
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\headerbox{Results 2: Discovery for unknown systems equations}{name=results2,column=2,span=2,row=0,below=results1,  bottomaligned= introduction}{%
    Empty but bottom  aligned with introduction bottom
}

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```